# Formatter intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatter

I'm using IntelliJ 2017.1 I'm attempting configure the formatter, I have the following code:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 1 || Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 2 || Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 3) {
    processArray[i] = new Process(initialTime, endTime);
}
```

When I press `Option + Command + L`, IntelliJ formats the code as follows:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 1 || Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 2 || Integer.parseInt(
        oneProcess[1]) == 3) {
    processArray[i] = new Process(burstTime, arrivalTime);
}
```

I want to configure the formatter as follows:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 1 || Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 2 || 
    Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 3) {
    processArray[i] = new Process(burstTime, arrivalTime);
}
```

This means that IntelliJ must do line jump when it exceeds the right margin and align with the previous condition.

I found `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces` but I can't configure as I explained before.

How can I configure the formatter?

Comment: it's about line length. Find line length or some thing like this and adjust it

Comment: @TuyenNguyen The margin on the right has `120 characters`, it is okay, I need to align each condition when it exceeds the margin

Answer (score 0):

I think that for easy to view, you should format like the formatter does. Because if the broke line are indented in the same space with the previous line then it lead to confused.
Example:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 1 || Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 2 || 
    Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 3) {
    processArray[i] = new Process(burstTime, arrivalTime);
}
```

This indent make others thought `Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]) == 3)` is the new line of code in the body. (My opinion)

If you have a line:

```
String x = x + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;"+ "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;";
```

Then you should indent like this:

```
    String x = x + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" 
         + "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;"
         + "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;";
```

Instead of this:

```
String x = x + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" 
+ "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;"
+ "d;asfkdsa;" + "dslkfajds" + "d;asfkdsa;";
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the solution I need